# Conditional probability for branching process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I am trying to figure out the probabilities for a branching process at an n'th step.

If i know, $P(X_2 = a | X_1 = b)$ and $P(X_1 = b | X_0 = c)$ $\forall b$ and the offspring distribution

how do I obtain $P(X_2 = a | X_0 = c)$ ?

A quick reminder would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can essentially look for all paths from $X_0 = c$ to $X_2=a$ and sum along their probabilities, since each path is disjoint.  To get to this we go through every possible $b$ that $X_1$ can take the value of.

$P(X_2 = a|X_0=c) = \displaystyle \sum_b P(X_2 = a|X_1=b) \cdot P(X_1=b|X_0=c)$

Comment: Exellent! That was my intuition!

Comment: The key word `Markov chain` is clearly missing from this answer.